# How would I convert a list of data frames to a list of matrices in r?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, matrix

I have a list of data frames from csv files read in as a list:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
csvfiles <- lapply(files, read.table)
class(csvfiles)
[1] "list"

class(csvfiles[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"
```

How would I convert each data frame into its own matrix in the list? I have tried `data.matrix(csvfiles)` but this just comes back with the following output which I don't believe is right:

```
      [,1]   
[1,] List,20
[2,] List,20
[3,] List,20
[4,] List,20
[5,] List,20
[6,] List,20
```

I have provided a reproducible list of data frames below:

```
set.seed(99)
no_1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 20)
df_1 <- data.frame(no_1)

set.seed(99999)
no_2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 20)
df_2 <- data.frame(no_2)

output_list <- list(df_1, df_2)
```

Comment: Since you want each data frame of the list to be converted into a matrix, you can use `lapply` to call as.matrix on each data frame. `lapply(output_list, as.matrix)` I would recommend looking into the apply set of functions and learning how they work.

Comment: ```simplify2array(output_list))``` may be helpful as well depending on what you want to do

Comment: Thanks @caldwellst and @Cole! These work well!

Comment: @Ruth or one of the answerers: please add as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want each data frame of the list to be converted into a matrix, you can use `lapply` to call `as.matrix` on each data frame. `lapply(output_list, as.matrix)` I would recommend looking into the apply set of functions and learning how they work.