# Coerce a list of data frames to a list of doubles

Tags: r, dataframe, list, double

I am trying to use the function `extractPosteriorMeans` in the R package `Siber` to to get the means of a set of Bayesian posterior distributions. Normally, one of the arguments used for `extractPosteriorMeans` is a list that looks like this:

[image: what I need my list to look like].

That list was created using the `siberMVN` function on a single dataset containing multiple combinations of groups and communities (in this case the year_tissuetype.AGE identifier). However, my own dataset had some constraints that forced me to run all of my group-community combinations separately. I am trying to combine the separate output data frames, which I tried to list together, so that they match the list format of the example. Here is a subset of what my list currently looks like (ignoring that the group-community IDs are different):

[image: what my data currently looks like].

I'm pretty far down an analytical pipeline, so fixing the problem that forced me to run my group-community combinations separately and string them together into a list after the fact would be much more complicated than just figuring out how to convert my list (`df_list`) to the same format as an actual `Siber` posterior list (`double_list`), so that it runs with the function `extractPosteriorMeans`. Can someone help me reformat `df_list` to the same list structure as `double_list`?

```
library(SIBER)

# Trying to create my own list here out of my data frame
df <- structure(list(Sigma2.1.1. = c(0.313422199359486, 0.367808733163473, 
0.287379338451926, 0.266462306294853), Sigma2.2.1. = c(0.543763352968645, 
0.729034607855539, 0.188017384643087, 0.10580503578473), Sigma2.1.2. = c(0.543763352968645, 
0.729034607855539, 0.188017384643087, 0.10580503578473), Sigma2.2.2. = c(1.90928916482304, 
2.63224559339719, 0.318783548730578, 0.25108375378826), mu.1. = c(-21.8944454084601, 
-21.6319111120951, -21.3223533707681, -21.2709073118823), mu.2. = c(4.72633431332481, 
4.80720104049834, 4.47663667743955, 4.61790878072818), group_comm_names = c("2019_claws.ADULT", 
"2019_claws.ADULT", "2019_claws.JU", "2019_claws.JU")), row.names = c(45001L, 
45002L, 54001L, 54002L), class = "data.frame")

df_list <- split(df[setdiff(names(df), "group_comm_names")], f = df$group_comm_names, drop = TRUE)
# but this list still doesn't have the right format for extractPosteriorMeans

# Here is an example list that I ran using siberMVN (i.e. the right way) 
# that is properly formatted. This is the goal format for my data.
double_list <- list(`2019_feathers.ADULT` = structure(c(0.321658761453638, 0.195543225238878, 
0.583801586825703, 0.26254908714109, 0.583801586825703, 0.26254908714109, 
1.89508038050268, 1.68514983009331, -21.8041135046668, -21.6033433747941, 
4.70782882682883, 4.76493678037111), dim = c(2L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Sigma2[1,1]", "Sigma2[2,1]", "Sigma2[1,2]", "Sigma2[2,2]", 
    "mu[1]", "mu[2]"))), `2021_feathers.ADULT` = structure(c(0.423467729835709, 
0.450662348987855, 0.145852582124701, 0.142899300399445, 0.145852582124701, 
0.142899300399445, 0.246099001638212, 0.34807362924927, -21.0033901314136, 
-20.980878158095, 4.60002257083648, 4.85210622120396), dim = c(2L, 
6L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Sigma2[1,1]", "Sigma2[2,1]", "Sigma2[1,2]", 
"Sigma2[2,2]", "mu[1]", "mu[2]"))))
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do here. Change list of dataframes to list of matrices?

Comment: Would you be able to shrink the example a little? Just a handful of rows/entries should be enough to figure out the logic.

Comment: are you trying to `unlist` your list? Its not clear what you mean

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback, I've shrunk down the lists to four rows each and tried to clarify the question. I don't think I'm trying to unlist my data necessarily, but the function I need to use next requires that the list entries have a "double" format rather than a "dataframe" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting too hung up class "double" and have realized I needed to convert my list of data frames to a list of matrices (thanks to @Ronak Shah), which now works perfectly. This post helped me figure it out[1]:

```
correct_list <- lapply(df_list,as.matrix)
```

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683507/how-would-i-convert-a-list-of-data-frames-to-a-list-of-matrices-in-r#:~:text=Since%20you%20want%20each%20data,lapply(output_list%2C%20as.